# Modifiers doesn't work in render

Tags: rendering, modifiers, 3d-view, subdivision-surface, project

I'm trying to create a 3D scene and noticed that the modifiers are not working on render.
I can see the modifiers in the 3D viewport, but not in the render. Idk what i have to do, do you know why the modifiers are not working?

Even if I create a new project, it's the same

Here is a simple example on a cube :

3D Viewport
[image: 3D Viewport]
Rendering
[image: Rendering]
Modifiers
[image: Modifiers]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can clearly see yourself that you had set the *Subdivision Surface* **"render value"** to *0*:[image]

Just set it to something above 0 and it will work.

Comment: oh thanks, i didn't know what this parameter was for.

Comment: @Alex No problem, have fun playing around !)